# Can't create new angular file

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, visual-studio-code, single-page-application

I code `ng new hello-world` but after I built it, I got this:

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Code\AngFirst\hello-world\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Code\AngFirst\hello-world\node_modules\karma\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> @angular/cli@8.0.3 postinstall C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Test Code\AngFirst\hello-world\node_modules@angular\cli
>   node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.9
>   (node_modules\fsevents):
>    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY:
>   Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.9: wanted
>   {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> added 1011 packages from 1041 contributors and audited 19005 packages in 447.952s
>   found 0 vulnerabilities
>
> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

- Angular CLI: 8.0.3
- node js : v10.16.0
- npm : 6.9.0

Answer (score 1):

This error

```
'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Seem like your computer cant find git instance so I would recommend install git [here](https://git-scm.com/downloads)

After your install git done

Try to dele node_modules folder and package-lock.json and run `npm i` again